# I can't log in to my website and can't find a mistake in elseif statement

Tags: php, if-statement, web

I'm getting a login error when trying to log into my website. I suspect the error may be in the `elseif` statement in the last part of the code because I'm not getting username or passwords or an empty error.  Can anyone see where the error is?

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include 'dbh.inc.php';
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);
    if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck < 1) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=username error");
            exit();
        } else {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
                if($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=password error");
                    exit();   
                } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                  //Log in the user here
                  $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                  $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
                  $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
                  $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                  $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
                  header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                  exit();   
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means "submit" is not set.

What is your submit button's **name**?

Change it to this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
```

the **name="submit"** is important